# Pass a header value from web-tier to EJB with @RequestScoped bean?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, cdi, requestscope

I should pass some information coming with a HTTP header from a request to an EJB and I don't want to add parameters and pass them everywhere I need them. So i used a RequestScoped bean to hold my header values. Is this implementation ok, or do I misunderstand the concept of @RecuestScoped beans?

First I get the headers with an interceptor (Resteasy), and save them into my **request scoped** bean:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class SomeInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor {

    @Inject
    ApplicationRequestContext appContext;

    @Override
    public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod resourceMethod)
            throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
        List<String> values = request.getHttpHeaders().getRequestHeader("Some-Header");
        if(values != null && values.size() > 0) {
            appContext.setSomeHeader(values.get(0));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the bean:

```
@RequestScoped
public class ApplicationRequestContext implements Serializable {
    private String someHeader;

    public void setSomeHeader(String someHeader) {
        this.someHeader = someHeader;
    }

    public String getSomeHeader() {
        return someHeader;
    }
}
```

Then I can access the value (different in every request) from my EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class CheckInWorkflow {

    @Inject
    ApplicationRequestContext appContext;

    public void someEjbMethod() {
        doSomethingWithThisHeaderValue(appContext.getSomeHeader());
    }
}
```

Based upon the description of [@RequestScoped](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html) this should work as expected:

> The request scope is active:
>
> - during the service() method of any servlet in the web application, during the doFilter() method of any servlet filter and when the container calls any ServletRequestListener or AsyncListener,
> - during any Java EE web service invocation,
> - during any remote method invocation of any EJB, during any asynchronous method invocation of any EJB, during any call to an EJB timeout method and
> - during message delivery to any EJB message-driven bean, and during any message delivery to a MessageListener for a JMS topic or queue obtained from the Java EE component environment.

Comment: What do your tests say? Does it do what you want? Does it work as you expect it to work?

Comment: The tests work so far... Also everything I read about CDI seem to correspond with my plan. It is more that I know of @RequestScope'd beans from the (web) context of ManagedBeans, so it feels unnatural to use this in my scenario.

Comment: If everything works as expected, and this solutions suits you, and what you're seeing matches with the documentation, you shouldn't be concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is correct, but it seems like an unnecessary optimization using side effects.